# CSS Positioning - Textarea with "Position: relative;" and "bottom: 0;" but not working?

Tags: css, browser, gmail, alignment

***Thanks for all the help you guys and gals, I found a different method to this problem. I will be using scrolling with all three inputs instead. If you find a solution to this problem, please let me know.***

I am having trouble creating a textarea that is both "Position: relative;" and "bottom: 0;".

I want the position relative so that the top of the textarea would be align with the bottom of another box. And the "bottom: 0;" so that the bottom of the textarea would always match the bottom of the browser, regardless of browser size.

I don't want to do any "height: px;" because I want the textarea to match any size. Honestly, I tried everything. Your help would greatly be appreciated.

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/W7uux (Problem is only for the mobile part).

Here is a picture of what I hope to accomplish:

[image]

---

I tried multiple positions already but none seems to get the result I wish:

1.) Just does not work at all. It only leaves the textarea its normal relative position.

```
textarea.form-control-combox {
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
}
```

2.) Only puts the textarea at the bottom.

```
textarea.form-control-combox {
width: 100vw;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

3.) Absolute is the worse of all because it overlaps everything.

```
textarea.form-control-combox {
width: 100vw;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

4.) This is as close as I could get to accomplish it. However, once I resize the browser the textarea overlaps the other boxes. Even if I put the same z-index, the textarea will still overlap.

```
textarea.form-control-combox {
width: 100vw;
position: fixed;
height: 85vh;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: take out the position:fixed and the bottom:0, it will snap to under the subject line, then just give it whatever height you want it to have.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still does not match the browser size. It tried height: em, px, vh, %; none produced the result desired. The em, px, are too static, different resolutions would be a problem. vh and % are either too large or too small depending on the browser size. Please take a look at the http://jsfiddle.net/W7uux  if you can. Thank you again.

Comment: honestly, take out the bottom border, give it a min height and let it resize as needed. As long as the container has the borders, 99% of people will never notice.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the entire thing in a `<div>` and apply `bottom: 0;` to that parent element?

Comment: @Luxelin Thanks for the tip, still no dice.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I wish I could do that but mobile, specifically, mobile keyboards would mess up the entire system. Someone would end up typing underneath the keyboard. I don't want that lol.

Comment: @umtek123 So something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/jkM9G/) is not what you're after? (I put a lot of `<br>`s so you can scroll).

Comment: @Luxelin Yes, I am looking for that, however, how would I make it so that the "To" and "Subject" also scrolled up? Nevermind, found the answer lol. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @umtek123 What do you mean by "scrolled up"? Do you want them to expand in height as more content is entered?

Answer (score 0):

Add `top: 0;` to your textarea style:

```
textarea.form-control-combox {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I also tried that but it didn't work. The textarea remained in its normal relative position.

Comment: One more thing to note: the problem is only in the mobile mode (max-width: 768px). And if I try 100vh, it overflows outside of the browser.

Comment: In the wider screen it's correct because you're using `height: 67%`, in other words, you're using a specific height.

Comment: Correct, that is why the desktop was easy to fix, but the mobile version (max-width: 768px) cannot have a specific height because each mobile phone has different height. Thats why I am in this conundrum. I am open to more than just CSS to solve this problem. You also have the problem of a mobile keyboard, which may drastically change the size.

Comment: It is absolutely fine. Thanks for trying though. I found a different solution, although it does not answer this specific question lol.